# STOPPED (CannotCreateContainerError: Error response from da)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS ECS tools suite. I'm trying to create a service that runs a task (having a docker image) on an EC2 instance inside the ECS cluster.

The service gets created, however, the task fails with the below error:

```
STOPPED (CannotCreateContainerError: Error response from da)
```

Not able to figure out the cause of this error, any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to the answer:

The Dockerfile which I had created was not correct and hence the container was not spawning up.